# OAuth mediator error: Unable to sendViaPost to url. javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-identity-server

At the beginning of the inSequence, I have an OAuth mediator.

```
<oauthService remoteServiceUrl="https://xx.xx.x.xxx:9444/services/" password="admin" username="admin"/>
```

wso2mi shows me this error:

> INFO {HTTPSender} - Unable to sendViaPost to
> url[https://10.22.0.234:9444/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService]
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

I used wso2is-5.11.0 and wso2mi-4.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an error using the same products that you describe.

The Support Team said me that IS 5.11.0 is not compatible with oauth mediator so you need to do a custom mediator or in a sequence do the call to validate the token.

This is my error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error while validating OAuth2 request
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediator.oauth.OAuth2TokenValidationServiceClient.validateAuthenticationRequest(OAuth2TokenValidationServiceClient.java:79)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediator.oauth.OAuthMediator.handleOAuth2(OAuthMediator.java:175)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://dto.oauth2.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd}tokenBinding
```

I add new news 29/03/2023:

WSO2 say me that it's probable they add a update that it resolves this problem.